# Reflecting an URLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to get all the information for an URLRequest in order to save it in a log. The problem comes when I try to do `String(reflecting: request)`. This method only gives my the final URL but not all the the other information such us body, httpMethod, encoding, etc.

However, if I do `po request`, I can see all the information of the request.

Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.description` and `.debugDescription` of an object to outpout a description.  These properties rely on the `CustomStringConvertible` and `CustomDebugStringConvertible` protocols respectively.

To change what is printed out you can define/redefine the conformance to the protocol.  As a trivial example for `URLRequest`:

```
extension URLRequest: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
   var debugDescription: String {
      """
      URL Request for \(self)
      full url \(self.url)
      header fields \(self.allHTTPHeaderFields)
      """
   }
}

let url = URL(string: "https://somedomain.com")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.addValue("ghuaidbwjkbdwd", forHTTPHeaderField: "Auhentication")
print(request.debugDescription)
```

will output

```
URL Request for https://somedomain.com
full url Optional(https://somedomain.com)
header fields Optional(["Auhentication": "ghuaidbwjkbdwd"])
```

Obviously you'd probably want to do something a bit more useful with the output but this should give you the tools.

When doing this for an object with a pre-defined conformance (eg. URLRequest, where it is defined in Foundation) you will get a warning about the previous implementation.

In this scenario, as the object already conforms to the description protocols, you can leave out re-conforming to it and just override the property.  So in the above example you should actually use

```
extension URLRequest {
   var debugDescription: String {
```

If the object you are working with is a class, you will need to mark this as an `override`.

If you want to get all the properties of the object you could use a Mirror.  You could define this directly on the object with an extension, but if it is something you are likely to use in more than one place maybe implement it via a protocol with a default implementation:

```
protocol Reflectable {
   func reflect()
}

extension Reflectable  {
   func reflect() {
      let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
      print("\(Self.self) for: \(self)")
      for item in mirror.children {
         print("\(String(describing: item.label)): \(item.value)")
      }
   }
}
```

You can then subscribe URLRequest to this and either access the `.reflect()` method directly or build it into either `CustomStringConvertible` or `CustomDebugStringConvertible`

```
extension URLRequest: Reflectable {}

request.reflect()
```

providing an output of:

```
URLRequest for: https://somedomain.com
Optional("url"): Optional(https://somedomain.com)
Optional("cachePolicy"): 0
Optional("timeoutInterval"): 60.0
Optional("mainDocumentURL"): nil
Optional("networkServiceType"): NSURLRequestNetworkServiceType
Optional("allowsCellularAccess"): true
Optional("httpMethod"): Optional("GET")
Optional("allHTTPHeaderFields"): Optional(["Auhentication": "ghuaidbwjkbdwd"])
Optional("httpBody"): nil
Optional("httpBodyStream"): nil
Optional("httpShouldHandleCookies"): true
Optional("httpShouldUsePipelining"): false
```